# Yii layout in controller

Tags: layout, yii

i'm a new one in Yii :)
I'm trying to generate CRUD structure with Gii and everything ok.
But i'm a little confused about overriding layout path in controller.

```
public $layout = '//layouts/column2';
```

How to explain such path, especially "//" part?

Comment: I recommend you to tag your question "PHP" also...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [`CController::getViewFile()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#getViewFile-detail). It explains the `//` and other view path options.

Comment: Simply put, it will first search for themes/themename/views for layouts/column2.php, failing to find it there, it will search protected/views for layouts/column2.php.  The link above will show how more complex resolution of this path works.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the template file column2.php has to be found under the default view directory for the application. That is : *protected/views*

Comment: Could you please show me the part of the code where it's processes